# Unable to replace the fragment in android 2.2

Tags: android-fragments

I am using the android v2.2, I have a listfragment and a displayfragment. I am able to create the  and also set the layout in the displayfragment during the onCreateView API call. But I am unable to replace the current layout with the different one. Following is the code:

It crashes during the commit() method call:

```
public class ActHotelEmenu extends FragmentActivity {
...
...
// This below function called when item clicked on the listfragment
//
 public void dispSubMenu(int position) {
        if(position == 1 || position == 0){
            MainDispMenuFragment f = MainDispMenuFragment.newInstance(position+1);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.main_layout,f); 
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);            
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();            
        } 
...
}
```

Please help me out in this...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a viewFlipper with each Fragment as a view of the viewFlipper, so you only have to use viewFlipper.showNext() and viewFlipper.showPrevious() to navegate between fragments.

Other posibility is to use a ViewPager like explain in this blog: http://tamsler.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-viewpager-and-fragments.html